# C# - String IndexOf method with second argument equal to String length

Tags: c#, .net

At some point in my code, I use this method:

```
IndexOf(string str, int startIndex)
```

I am also doing some calculations before, and I invoke this method with second argument (startIndex) equal to length of a string passed as first argument.
Of course, no such an index exists in a string, and if we did something like this:

```
string[string.Length]
```

we would get an `IndexOutOfRangeException`

How does that method work exactly? In MSDN documentation it is clearly said, that startIndex is zero-based index of a string. Does it work and doesn't throw because a char array that `String` class operates on is null-terminated?
I want to make sure that my program won't throw at any point.

Comment: A string `ABCD` has a length of 4, but the indexes are `[0,1,2,3]`. The maximum available index is always going to be `str.Length-1`.

Comment: use string[string.Length-1]

Comment: @ZevSpitz is right. So, what you should do is string[string.Length - 1].

Comment: Guys did you at least read my question? Lol. I know that maximum index is string.Length -1. I have stated that if we do string[string.Length] we will get IndexOutOfRangeException because no such an index exists... really..

Comment: Perhaps you should clarify a bit better that you're asking why    `str.IndexOf(anotherString, str.Length)` doesn't throw an exception, even though `str[str.Length]` does throw an exception. (Technically, _I invoke this method_ doesn't mean you invoke it successfully; and there might be a `try..catch` around it).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's mentioned explicitly in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7cct0x33(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Index numbering starts from 0. The startIndex parameter can range from
>   0 to the length of the string instance. **If startIndex equals the
>   length of the string instance, the method returns -1**.

Comment: I'm still wondering about the reasoning behind this. `s.IndexOf('.', s.Length+1);` does throw the `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`, so why does `s.IndexOf('.', s.Length);` not throw?

Comment: @RenéVogt: because that is how the method was implemented. Someone found it useful to not throw an exception in this specific case. Maybe they want to handle this case for VB6-migrated apps that have 1-based indexes or VB developers which are still not familiar with zero based indexes. You could argue that it's correct to return -1 if you search the index of a string at the end of another string.

Comment: I know that short answer "because it's implemented like that". Wondered about the _reasoning_.

Comment: Looks like I missed that sentence. Thnx @RenéVogt

Comment: I guess the "searching at the end of a string" is a good point. It makes the code for loops searching consecutive appearances of a substring a little more compact. thx for the hint.

Comment: @RenéVogt I've also been wondering about it for a while. In my program I am iterating over whole string, and at the end my variable I use for iteration is equal to Length of a string, not Length - 1. Maybe that's what it is for.

Comment: @MindRoller: the implementation of a .NET method can change and you should trust documentation or specification(if avaiable). But since you have asked how the method works exactly. You can always look at the [source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/globalization/compareinfo.cs,85e3ffb17534f9ef,references). Unfortunately this is in the unmanaged [`IndexOfString`](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/775003a4c72f0acc37eab84628fcef541533ba4e/src/utilcode/newapis.cpp#L775). Look at the _"// else iRetVal = -1 (not found)"_ comment.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I don’t believe that C++ code you found is the actual source used for “normal” .NET platforms though. The one you found is part of the *downlevel* emulation which I believe is only used on some minor platforms (could be wrong about that though, no idea).

Comment: @TimSchmelter I just missed that sentence "If startIndex equals the length of the string instance, the method returns -1" in the documentation. Will read more carefully next time. That's all I needed :) so thanks for it!

Answer (score 3):

[To the source!](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/mscorlib/src/System/String.Searching.cs#L32)

```
public unsafe int IndexOf(char value, int startIndex, int count) {
    if (startIndex < 0 || startIndex > Length)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(startIndex), Environment.GetResourceString("ArgumentOutOfRange_Index"));

    if (count < 0 || count > Length - startIndex)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(count), Environment.GetResourceString("ArgumentOutOfRange_Count"));

    fixed (char* pChars = &m_firstChar)
    {
        char* pCh = pChars + startIndex;

        while (count >= 4)
        {
            // .. some search
        }

        while (count > 0)
        {
            // .. some search
        }
    }

    return -1;
}
```

As you can see, the `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` is only thrown when using a `startIndex` that is **larger** than the length of the string. Since you are passing the length itself, this is not a problem. If you were to pass a number larger than it, you would see the exception:

```
Console.WriteLine("foo".IndexOf('a', 3)); // -1
Console.WriteLine("foo".IndexOf('a', 4)); // throws ArgumentOutOfRangeException
```

Now, we’re not actually calling the `IndexOf` shown above. Instead we are calling the following signature:

```
public int IndexOf(char value, int startIndex) {
    return IndexOf(value, startIndex, this.Length - startIndex);
}
```

So for the `count` parameter above, the value `this.Length - startIndex` is passed. Since `startIndex` is equal to the length, `count` will be zero.

So the two while loops we see in the implementation above will not execute at all. And thus, the default result `-1` is returned.

(Small note: I’m using the .NET Core source since the [.NET Framework reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,2225) does not include the source of this method. The implementations should be mostly identical though.)

---

As for why you can begin your search *after* the end of the string, I have a simple explanation that could be the reason. If you look at a string, you can start searching at multiple points. Let’s use `"foo bar"` as the string:

```
Index:        0 1 2 3 4 5 6
Character:    f o o   b a r
Points:      ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑
             0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

As you can see, there are 8 points before or after a character for a string of length 7. When you specify things like a start index, you aren’t actually talking about the character index, but the point index of the space in between the characters. This is evident by a use of `"foo bar".Substring(5, 1)` where you get the characters between point 5 and point 6 (5+1). This is also why `str.Substring(str.Length)` is an actually logical use to get the empty string that’s at the end of the string.

Answer (score 2):

From [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7cct0x33%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> If startIndex equals the length of the string instance, the method returns -1.

As to *why* it doesn't throw an exception if `index==length` like array accessors do, the framework designers would have to answer that since the documentation doesn't say, and the C# source code eventually calls an internal C function..  Some uneducated guesses:

- Backward compatibility with legacy string functions
- Unicode support

Answer (score 2):

[MSDN](http://ArgumentOutOfRangeException%09%20%20startIndex%20is%20less%20than%200%20(zero)%20or%20greater%20than%20the%20length%20of%20this%20string.) clearly states what exceptions it can throw.  For example:

> ArgumentOutOfRangeException
>
> startIndex is less than 0 (zero) or greater than the length of this
>   string.

It goes on to say:

> Index numbering starts from 0. The startIndex parameter can range from
>   0 to the length of the string instance. If startIndex equals the
>   length of the string instance, the method returns -1.

So there's really no guesswork required regarding exceptions.